# angularjs passy masonry - TypeError: element.masonry is not a function

Tags: angularjs, masonry

I'm having this error using the passy masonry. Any idea what does it mean?Cause basically right now the masonry doesn't work for me at all.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your question is too broad. Please read [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what the cause of your issue is, but I was just dealing with the same thing, and I was able to resolve it by messing around with dependencies. After some trial and error, I noticed that I was missing a dependency for one of angular-masonry's dependecies, called jquery-bridget. I am not sure why this isn't being installed with bower-install, perhaps there is an issue with the bower.json, but anyways, if you do

```
bower uninstall --save angular-masonry
```

and then

```
bower install --save jquery-bridget
bower install --save angular-masonry
```

it MAY fix your problem. Once again, not entirely sure if this is the same issue or whether there was something wonky with my set up that I had messed up. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly same problem before and solved by just changed "jquery.bridget.js" loading position.

```js
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>

<script src="bower_components/jquery-bridget/jquery.bridget.js"></script>

<script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-local-storage/dist/angular-local-storage.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/get-style-property/get-style-property.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/get-size/get-size.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/eventie/eventie.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/doc-ready/doc-ready.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/eventEmitter/EventEmitter.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/matches-selector/matches-selector.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/outlayer/item.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/outlayer/outlayer.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/masonry/masonry.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/imagesloaded/imagesloaded.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-masonry/angular-masonry.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
```

Comment: works for me. I had to load jquery.bridget before masonry and imagesLoaded

Answer (score 1):

You need to install [jquery bridget](https://github.com/desandro/jquery-bridget) plugin:

```
bower install --save jquery-bridget
```

If you use grunt-wiredep, than you should get the following order of scripts in your html (second part of scripts list should have **exactly** the same order: jquery.bridget.js and then other scripts!) :

```
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/vendor/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="/vendor/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="/vendor/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>

<script src="/vendor/jquery-bridget/jquery.bridget.js"></script>
<script src="/vendor/get-style-property/get-style-property.js"></script>
<script src="/vendor/get-size/get-size.js"></script>
<script src="/vendor/eventie/eventie.js"></script>
<script src="/vendor/doc-ready/doc-ready.js"></script>
<script src="/vendor/eventEmitter/EventEmitter.js"></script>
<script src="/vendor/matches-selector/matches-selector.js"></script>
<script src="/vendor/outlayer/item.js"></script>
<script src="/vendor/outlayer/outlayer.js"></script>
<script src="/vendor/masonry/masonry.js"></script>
<script src="/vendor/imagesloaded/imagesloaded.js"></script>
<script src="/vendor/angular-masonry/angular-masonry.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
```

And here is a part of my **bower.json** file:

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "~2.1.4",
    "angular": "~1.3.15",
    "angular-resource": "~1.3.15",
    "angular-route": "~1.3.15",
    "angular-masonry": "~0.11.0",
    "jquery-bridget": "~1.1.0"
  }
}
```

With all this configuration angurlar-masonry is working as expected.